# Windows: Run application when USB device is plugged in

Tags: windows, winapi, usb

I need to start application "X" when a serial device is plugged into a USB port (or perhaps any device and "X" may filter). One method is to keep a running monitor app, checking the ports and fire "X" upon detecting a 'new' serial port. I'm doing it reading the following Registry entries every few seconds:

```
          HKLM/Hardware\DeviceMap\SerialComm
```

Good enough for now however, I will like something more direct without a 'monitor' running.

Comment: [Device Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363432(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Expect this not to work. Any sensible sysadmin will block any such capability since it is a malware infection vector.